# Using .on() and e.stopPropagation() on dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have been experimenting with capturing click events outside of elements using `stopPropagation()`.

```
$(".container").children().on('click',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();    
});
$(".container").on("click",function(){
  alert("outside the box?");    
})​
```

[Here is a jsFiddle set up to demonstrate it functioning](http://jsfiddle.net/2YNbp/). An alert should fire when you click anywhere outside of the white box.

Now, I am trying to have the same principle applied to dynamically created elements. As far as I understand, the `on()` method of event assignment in jQuery should allow this to function without changing the script.

[Here is a second jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GsLtN/1/) where you must first click a link to create the elements. Once you have done this, the theory is that the same script will work, but it does not. What am I missing about this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short word you need to put `on()` on existing parent element to make it works:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<div class="container"><div class="box"></div></div>').appendTo('body');
    $(this).remove();
});

$('body').on('click', '.container > *', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();    
});

$('body').on('click', '.container', function(){
  alert("outside the box?");    
})​
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/GsLtN/5/

For more detail check ['.on()'](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on official site at section 'Direct and delegated events'

Comment: Spot on. Little explanation as to why would awesome.

Comment: @MildFuzz: See my answer for explanation. Had not seen this answer, he must have hit post seconds before. Anyways.

Answer (score 7):

When the item is added dynamically, you should attach the handler to the closest parent that will surely be there - in your case this is `body`. You can use [`on()` this way to achieve a functionality](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) that [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) used to offer:

> > $(*selector-for-parent*).on(*events*, *selector-for-dynamic-children*, *handler*);

So your code rewritten would simply be this:

```
$("body").on('click', '.container', function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.hasClass('container')) {
        alert("outside the box!");
    }
});
```

I used [`e.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to find which element actually triggered the event. In this case, I identify the item by checking whether it has the `container` class.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GsLtN/9/)

Comment: nice solution. Does this affect my ability to remove the binding? When binding events to dynamic elements, I generally like to remove the binding with the event to guard against memory drainage.

Comment: @MildFuzz If you want to remove the event handlers, you can use `.off()` (on `body` of course in this case). I normally [namespace](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) my events, to make removal easier. This means I attach on `click.MyNameSpace` instead of simply `click`. But the trick here is that you actually do not need to remove the event handler, because it is not bound to the dynamic element itself - you only need to remove it when you know that no more dynamic items of this type will be added.

Comment: So the event binding itself does not consume memory?

Comment: @MildFuzz No matter how many `.container` elements you insert into `body`, there will still be only ONE event handler attached - on `body`. Much less memory consumption then in the case of attaching the handler on `.container` elements themselves, and you don't have to attach/unattach the events all the time, event delegation solves it all for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the `.on()` to a parent.

What you're trying to do is - bind the handler to a parent that listens for an event, then checks whether the event was triggered by an element that matches that selector.

```
$("body").on("click", '.container',function(){
  alert("outside the box?");    
})​
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/GsLtN/2/)

Answer (score 2):

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/GsLtN/4/)***

When you bind a event handler to a element use `.on`, the target you bind to must exist in the domcument.

```
$('body').on('click', '.container > *', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();    
});
$('body').on("click",'.container',function(){
  alert("outside the box?");    
})​
```

Comment: does this mean that I can't remove the event binding? I always like to clean up my bindings to avoid memory drainage.

Comment: @MildFuzz You can still remove your bindings with `.off()`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`.

You will have to bind the event to a parent container. Perhaps something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/mhusaini/jpKCt/).