# Javascript Child Selector Not Being Called

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selector

http://jsfiddle.net/w8ak1yyy/7/

The project is to create colors based off the child. I am focusing on fixing the LEFT div (GREEN box). However when I try to create more divs off of the left most box (GREY), it keeps calling the parent div (GREEN). It does not create a div off the child clicked.

Now I am trying to stop propagation to limit the event call only on the child, but the specific selectors never select the child.

LINE 38:

```
$(".left-child").click(function(event){
        propStopped( event );
        event.stopPropagation();
        propStopped( event );
        alert("Found child");
    });
```

this code should target the child element but doesn't, and I also tried the following selectors below and they also didn't find the child.

```
$(".left-child")
$(".left > .left-child")
$("div.left" > .left-child")
```

The end result for now should be making more divs to the left by clicking the left most div.
Line 63 begins appending the left div.

I placed a counter that displays on the div being clicked on, which updates the parent div(GREEN) rather than the child.

Comment: You can't attach an event to an element that doesn't exist yet. Use event delegation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You can't operate on a dynamic element since it hasn't been created at the point your code is called. This should provide an answer for what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088460/using-on-and-e-stoppropagation-on-dynamic-elements

Answer (score 3):

You can't attach an event to an element that doesn't exist yet. You should use event delegation:

```
$(".left").on("click", ".left-child", function(event){
    propStopped( event );
    event.stopPropagation();
    propStopped( event );
    alert("Found child");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The child element is called properly here.